# Issues installing a python module within virtual environment on a linux server

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm attempting to install a python package ([ensembleRNA](https://github.com/cbtolson/ensemblerna_package)) within a virtual environment (running python 3.9) on a linux server. My problem arises when attempting to install this package as a python module as instrctucted by the man page. The setup script is somehow invoking a different python interpreter outside my virtual environment, and subsequently installation fails because the dependencies cannot be found. Is this expected behavior? Should I be trying to install this package on the root rather than a virtual environment if I can't figure out this issue?

To add a little more detail: The man page instructs me to run`sudo python setup.py install`. Using `sudo` uses the root, and subsequently in the error messages I see that python 2.7 is being invoked. Running just `python setup.py install` yields a permission denied error, likely because of the hierarchy of the server. I would rather not install the dependencies for this package on the root for obvious reasons as this is a shared server, so does anyone have an idea of how I can get this module installed in my virtual environment?

Thanks so much in advance, please let me know if any additional information can be helpful.

Comment: Its common to use `python3` on linux servers, so `sodo python3 setup.py`. Usually you don't need the `sudo` for a virtual environment. You want a user space install. It could be that something has gone wrong with the venv in the bad install. I think you should wipe it completely and start over without at `sudo` at all. After creating the venv, run `which python3` and if that's in the venv, go ahead with the rest `python3 -m pip install ensembleRNA`. If you still get a error, post it so we can see.  But something called "ensemblRNA" just doesn't sound like it will need elevated rights.

Comment: When you do `sudo python`, you're likely dropping any environment `PATH` settings (like what `virtualenv` would set) and instead relying on whatever has been set for the path used while `sudo`ing. What are the errors you're getting when just trying to run this in `virtualenv`? Any error traces?

Comment: The `sudo` would be used if you want to install into the operating system's python. That can lead to problems because the OS python is also controlled by the OS package manager (rpm / deb). Mixing pip with those can get messy.

Comment: @wkl Running python setup.py install in the venv produces the following:

`creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/eggerror: could not create 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg': Permission denied`

This issue persisted even in a new virtual environment. This sounds like a server-related security obstacle?

Comment: @NickF - are you reusing directories that you tried to do `sudo` in earlier? There may be files or directories owned by `root` if so. If that’s the case, delete everything in the `build` directory and try again (or alternatively `chown` everything to proper perms and owners).

Comment: @wkl good suggestion, I deleted build and  the install appeared to work this time. However upon testing I got an error. Here are the last two traces:
`File "/mnt/storage2/stonelab/miniconda3/envs/ensemblerna/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1441, in run_script
    exec(code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/home/stonelab/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ensemblerna-1.0-py3.5.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/ensemblerna", line 2, in <module>
    from ensemblerna.main import main
ImportError: No module named 'ensemblerna'` Why am I seeing paths outside the venv?